# SharePoint Database Attach Upgrade Problem

Tags: 2010

I have follow the steps to upgrade SHP2007 to SHP2010 using the database attach method.
The content database was upadated successfully and attached to a new web application.

Here are my three problems so far.
1-The web application is not displaying but my old 2007 data is not showing.
Is there any step that I have missed? There is no other database attach to the web application.

2-The other error I am gettig is when I run the test database command.
Category        : MissingWebPart
Error           : True
UpgradeBlocking : False
Message         : WebPart class [f4b61a9b-a3d0-8d94-0eed-a84ee19b26c6] is referenced [2] times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on
                   the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part.
Remedy          : One or more web parts are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any f
                  eature or solution which contains these web parts.

When I search in SQL by the id, is refering to a mysite webpart. WebUrl="mysite".

3-Visual upgrade is diasable, grayed out.

Any idea what I did or might be doing wrong?

I havent attached any other database. I am waiting to resolve this issues.
At least I will like to be able to see my 2007 site running under 2010.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by "The web application is not displaying but my old 2007 data is not showing"

Comment: The site is not displaying the data from the SP2007 site.

Comment: So it's showing an empty site? Is the site you're upgrading located at the root of the URL, i.e. domain.com/ or in a managed path, domain.com/sites/sitename? Go to Central Admin - Application Managmeent - View All Site Collections. Select your web app, do you see two listed here?

Answer (score 1):

> 1 - The web application is not displaying but my old 2007 data is not
>   showing. Is there any step that I have missed? There is no other
>   database attach to the web application.

Attach a content database to a Web application and then Verify that upgrade succeeded for the database, and review the site to see if there are any issues. Perform this step for one content database in your environment. This step might take an hour, several hours, or longer, depending on your data set and hardware on the Web servers, database servers, and storage subsystem. Did you get any issues in the Upgrade logs (can be accessed using Central Admin)

> 2 - The other error I am getting is when I run the test database
>   command.
>
> > Category : MissingWebPart Error : True UpgradeBlocking : False Message
> >     : WebPart class [f4b61a9b-a3d0-8d94-0eed-a84ee19b26c6] is referenced
> >     [2] times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the
> >     current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this
> >     web part. Remedy : One or more web parts are referenced in the
> >     database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the current farm.
> >     Please install any f eature or solution which contains these web
> >     parts.

You can identify the WebParts and the page by querying the SQL Server (not recommended by Microsoft though)

```
select AllDocs.SiteId, WebId, Webs.Title as‘Web Title‘, ListId, DirName, LeafName from AllDocs innerjoin WebParts on AllDocs.Id = WebParts.tp_PageUrlID innerjoin Webs on AllDocs.WebId = Webs.Id where WebParts.tp_WebPartTypeID =’f4b61a9b-a3d0-8d94-0eed-a84ee19b26c6′
```

> 3 - Visual upgrade is disable, grayed out.

Have you tried enabling the Visual upgrade using the PowerShell below?

```
 foreach($site in $Mywebapplication.Sites)
    {

            foreach($web in $site.AllWebs)
            {  
                write-host "In the Site Collection URL " $site.Url  "## In the web Named " $web.Name -foregroundcolor Yellow
                $web.UIVersion = 4
                $web.UIVersionConfigurationEnabled = 1
                $web.Update();                
                $web.Dispose();
            }          
            $site.Dispose();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.

1- The database upgraded successfully. After deleting a few broken sites. When I test the database it only gives me error about the web part missing.

2- I am going to try this. Any other suggestion?

3- No, I have not try to enable using PowerShell. Going to try.

Thanks

Comment: SQL is giving errors. SELECT AllDocs.SiteId,
       WebId,
       Webs.Title AS WebTitle,
       ListId,
       DirName,
       LeafName
FROM AllDocs 
INNER JOIN WebParts ON AllDocs.Id = WebParts.tp_PageUrlID 
INNER JOIN Webs ON AllDocs.WebId = Webs.Id
WHERE WebParts.tp_WebPartTypeID ='f4b61a9b-a3d0-8d94-0eed-a84ee19b26c6'

Comment: After running this:stsadm.exe -o enumallwebs -includewebparts > C:\enumwebs.txt
I found on the log that there is an user who's "MySite" is hosted under a "/mysite" directory.
All my users "MySites" are under the directory "/personal".
<Web Id="bec74957-8ee9-4bb2-bc2e-0de470e9fae6" Url="/mysite" LanguageId="1033" TemplateName="SPSMSITEHOST#0" TemplateId="54">